# OpenCL kernel compilation time

Tags: opencl, fpga, hpc

I am new to the FPGA world. I tried to compile some OpenCl programs, but I noticed that it takes very long time to compile even the "Hello_World" program (couple hours). So that I am wondering why compiling OpenCL kernel on FPGA's takes long time (hours)? In addition, did the FPGA get re-programmed when we compile/execute the OpenCl on it?

Answer (score 0):

Converting sequential code to hardware is difficult, and in some cases the compiler tries multiple versions of things to find the most optimal combination of hardware. It's not like compiling for CPUs and GPUs, so the workflow is quite different (you compile kernels at build time and not runtime). The end result is often hardware that is faster and/or uses less energy than more general purpose compute devices like CPUs and GPUs. There are some excellent "OpenCL on Altera" videos that explain how the compilation works, but a summary is: Compile to a abstract machine, and for each instruction/step, remove the abstract machine hardware not needed for that step, then merge all the remaining hardware into what gets programmed on the chip. The data "flows" through the hardware rather than living in memory and registers like it does on a CPU/GPU.